How do I restore the color of a down jacket?
I just bought this jacket and after washing it by hand once, it has two colors now. Some parts are pale blue and some parts are deep blue. It is a "North Face" brand down jacket. What should I do now?


Assuming that it’s new, contact the manufacturer?

It appears the dark blue area might have oil on it, making it darker. You could try washing again, using detergent specifically for down, to see if it lightens that area. If so, it might require multiple washings.
